# JPA select from collection with many-to-many association

Tags: java, jpa, collections, many-to-many

I have 2 Entity classes with Many-to-Many association.

ModPm:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MOD_PM")
public class ModPm extends WebPageObject implements Serializable, IDBNamedEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public final static String Q_GET_WITHOUT_STATUS_FOR_SCOPE = "ModPm.getWithoutStatusForScope";

    @Id
    private long id;
    ....
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "MOD_PM_SCOPE_TYPES",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PM_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "SCOPE_TYPE_ID")
    )
    private List<ModScopeType> modScopeTypes;
```

ModScopeType:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MOD_SCOPES")
@Cacheable
public class ModScopeType extends WebPageObject implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public final static String Q_GET_ALL = "ModScopeType.getAll";

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;
    ....
    //bi-directional many-to-many association to ModPm
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "MOD_PM_SCOPE_TYPES",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "SCOPE_TYPE_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PM_ID")
    )
    private List<ModPm> modPms;
```

Is it possible to select entities from MOD_PM table which have record in MOD_PM_SCOPE_TYPES table for SCOPE_TYPE_ID=1?

Native SQL Query:

```
SELECT ID, NAME FROM MOD_PM WHERE ID IN (SELECT PM_ID FROM MOD_PM_SCOPE_TYPES WHERE SCOPE_TYPE_ID=1)
```

How can I translate this query to JPQL?

Comment: The ModScopeType class has a Table annotation called MOD_SCOPES don't you mean a record int he MOD_SCOPES table?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you refer to SCOPE_TYPE_ID in the query what are you referring to? Could be the ID of ScopeType or another field that I'm not seeing. I'm assuming the scope type id field is missing.

Try this:

```
select p from ModPm p join p.modScopeTypes type where type.scopeTypeId = 1
```

Comment: Thx, worked fine for me. SCOPE_TYPE_ID is field of MOD_PM_SCOPE_TYPES table, which have 2 columns - PM_ID and SCOPE_TYPE_ID, each referenced to primary key column of tables MOD_PM and MOD_SCOPE_TYPES